# Installer for JAVA application and run it as a windows-service

Tags: java, jar, windows-services, windows-installer

I have a JAR file with a simple JAVA application. This JAR file needs two command line arguments to run.
I want to make an installer, which can call this arguments and run my JAR with the given parameters as a Windows-service.

Is there any tool for this problem?

Comment: Can you please provide some more details

Comment: There are a few tools that can create a native Windows service for a java app and which allow you to pass paramteres to the jar file. Free tools: Wix or commercial tools: InsallShield, AdvancedInstaller etc.